# Chemical smell from older Viking Gas (propane) Range

Tags: oven

I have a Viking Gas Range that runs on propane for 20 years. Lately, when I use the stove to bake something I'll get a crazy chemical smell. It happens about every 3rd time I use the stove. I end up taking out what's baking and finishing it in a toaster oven. This is not a propane/gas smell. It's an incredibly strong toxic chemical smell. It permeates the entire kitchen and dining room area. Any ideas? Do I need a new stove?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried contacting Viking? Being a high end product, I would expect them to have a high quality customer service.

Comment: Ok a chemical smell like sulfur? Rotten eggs? Is there a drip leg at the stove? 1 pipe that points down and capped (this is to catch excess water and rust) I would check with your gas company.

Comment: Avoid the word "toxic" unless you've seen something get sick or die.    If you are dead certain it's not a propane leak (and your provider recently changed the chemicals used to infuse propane with a smell), then  my money is on something that fell inside somewhere  and is getting baked every time you fire up the oven.  Try running empty at 500F for 6 hours (assuming nothing catches fire)  and see if  that destroys all the outgassing material.

Comment: is one of your pots missing a handle?